# Query "on" clause not limiting join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the query as below, what it is meant to do is

> Return id of all submissions into competition 2 including a count of how many times they have been read.

Which it is doing everything fine, except it's returning rows from all other competitions as well; Why is it not only joining where `` `competition_id` = 2 ``?

```
SELECT 
    `c`.`competition_id`,
    `c`.`submission_id`,
    COUNT(
      `submission_reads`.`submission_id`
    ) `reads` 
  FROM
    `submission_reads` 
    RIGHT JOIN `competition_submissions` c 
      ON `c`.`submission_id` = `submission_reads`.`submission_id` 
      AND c.top_round = 1 
      AND c.`competition_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `c`.`submission_id`
```

Comment: move competition_id = 2 to where clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `RIGHT` join, you get all rows from the table on the right; the `ON` clause limits the matching rows from the table on the left, i.e. the `submission_reads` table. If you want to limit rows of `competition_submissions`, you need to change the join from `RIGHT` to `LEFT`.

> *comment:* "I want all rows from the `competition_submissions` table regardless to whether it has an entry in the `submission_reads`"

Then you need to make `c.competition_id = 2` part of the `WHERE` clause, because you want it to filter the rows of the "main" table in the outer join:

```
SELECT 
    `c`.`competition_id`,
    `c`.`submission_id`,
    COUNT(
      `submission_reads`.`submission_id`
    ) `reads` 
  FROM
     `competition_submissions` c 
    LEFT JOIN `submission_reads` r
      ON `c`.`submission_id` = `r`.`submission_id` 
      AND `c`.top_round = 1 
  WHERE `c`.`competition_id` = 2 
  GROUP BY `c`.`submission_id`
```

Comment: AH I see, and so if I want all rows from the `competition_submissions` table regardless to whether it has an entry in the `submission_reads` table then leave the query as is but add a `WHERE `c`.`competition_id` = 2`?

Comment: @Hailwood - Yeh you need to put the condition in `WHERE` clause. See [this simple SQLFiddle sample demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3649d/6)